# Freelance Web Developer Stationary for Estimates, Proposals, Contracts

Tags: contracts, invoices

I'm about to start my freelance web development/design business, as a sole trader. My website is set up, and ranking well, and I've already received quite a few requests for estimates/quotes on a project.

I am at the stage where I have a good estimate, and have a decent quote that I think the client will find attractive.

My problem is, I don't have any formal templates to submit my quote. I refuse to submit a bog standard email, I want to attach a PDF which I will create myself, but on this PDF will be a full breakdown of costs, preliminary timelines etc. I dont really know what to put on this, how to word it or structure it.

Does anyone have access to, or know where I can access, a basic library of templates for such things? I suppose this will include a template for a Quote, Terms and Conditions, Contract to exchange business, and Invoices.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, you may want to consult/hire a lawyer to prepare the **Terms and Conditions** and your **Contract**. Of course, you prepare what you need included there and the lawyer should wrap it around with the legal attributes and requirements of the country you are living in/doing business.

**Invoices** - There are many accounting softwares (both free and paid). I am personally a fan of FreshBooks.com (has a free plan with no time restrictions, that does the trick for me). If you want additional functionality such as over 3 clients and sending real/paper invoices to your clients you may want to look into other plans or other products. *DISCLAIMER: I am not affiliated with the above site, this is just a personal opinion.*

**Quote** - I've seen many many different and creative ways to request information from the client and provide quotes on the prices of your services. Personally, I would go with something minimalistic, but well designed. Remember, this is usually where the client decides whether or not he should go with you or the other freelances. Of course, this doesn't mean that you can't provide complex packages or product bundles - just don't bombard your client with information at first sight. (That's why most designer's websites have a "request a quote" option, instead of simply placing dozens and dozens of scenarios and prices on the website itself)

As for templates, I would suggest you check out the following great examples. Even if they don't do the trick for you, they are still pretty good for motivation:

[http://speckyboy.com/2010/08/12/5-free-to-use-freelance-design-contract-templates/](http://develop-a-website.com/10-freelance-web-design-contract-templates-and-samples)

http://www.leemunroe.com/freelance-document-templates/

http://develop-a-website.com/10-freelance-web-design-contract-templates-and-samples